# My REST API Return Nothing

Tags: java, xml, rest, entitymanager

I have a entity class Workplaces.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workplaces")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Workplaces.findAll", query = "SELECT w FROM Workplaces w"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Workplaces.findBySpId", query = "SELECT w FROM Workplaces w WHERE w.spId = :spId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Workplaces.findByWorkers", query = "SELECT w FROM Workplaces w WHERE w.workers = :workers"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Workplaces.findByLatitude", query = "SELECT w FROM Workplaces w WHERE w.latitude = :latitude"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Workplaces.findByLongitude", query = "SELECT w FROM Workplaces w WHERE w.longitude = :longitude")})
public class Workplaces implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "sp_id")
    private Integer spId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "workers")
    private int workers;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private float latitude;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private float longitude;

    public Workplaces() {
    }

    public Workplaces(Integer spId) {
        this.spId = spId;
    }

    public Workplaces(Integer spId, int workers, float latitude, float longitude) {
        this.spId = spId;
        this.workers = workers;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Integer getSpId() {
        return spId;
    }

    public void setSpId(Integer spId) {
        this.spId = spId;
    }

    public int getWorkers() {
        return workers;
    }

    public void setWorkers(int workers) {
        this.workers = workers;
    }

    public float getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(float latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public float getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(float longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (spId != null ? spId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Workplaces)) {
            return false;
        }
        Workplaces other = (Workplaces) object;
        if ((this.spId == null && other.spId != null) || (this.spId != null && !this.spId.equals(other.spId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.rest.api.Workplaces[ spId=" + spId + " ]";
    }

}
```

The snippet of my WorkplacesFacadeREST.java

```
@Stateless
@Path("com.rest.api.workplaces")
public class WorkplacesFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Workplaces> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.rest_hiring_challenge_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public WorkplacesFacadeREST() {
        super(Workplaces.class);
    }

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public Workplaces find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    return super.find(id);
}

@GET
@Override
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Workplaces> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}
```

I tried request `http://localhost:8080/hiring_challenge/com.rest.api.workplaces/500015631`. I know primary key id `500015631` exists in my mysql db's `workplaces` table. I also tried: `http://localhost:8080/hiring_challenge/com.rest.api.workplaces/`. The result page just shows:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

and nothing else.

**UPDATE:**
I was missing MySQL's jdbc driver. After adding that, the project worked.

Comment: Are you sure that `SELECT w FROM Workplaces w...` is what you want ? not `select * ...` ?

Comment: Further, you write `SELECT w FROM Workplaces w WHERE w.spId = :spId` but later on `@Column(name = "sp_id")` which one is the column name in the DB: spId or sp_id ?

Comment: Are you using the newest version of Firefox and if not could you retry accessing the rest service with it? Another option for debugging would be using a HttpClient like the JAX RS Client in this example (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs-client001.htm) and setting a break point to check the data contained by the Response´s entity.

Comment: Apart from that the queries seems to be correct. This are JPQL queries (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language) and executed at object level with the name of the properties. @Column is an annotation for overriding the default mapping of the field spId's name and the database.

Comment: Just a tiny check to rule out the possibility: try adding some logging to the REST methods. Are they actually invoked at all?

Comment: @ptk93 is correct. This is JPQL query. `select w From Workplaces w...` should be the case. I'm using the newest Firefox version. I tried on Chrome too. Will try JAX RS Client to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that your JAX-RS Service is not registered in the web.xml or a sub class of javax.ws.rs.core.Application?

One way is to set the application path in your web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Another option would be packaging your application with a @ApplicationPath annotated class that extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest/api")
public class RESTConfig extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application{ }
```

The path "rest/api" is just an example, you could also set it to the root, but for deploying JAX-RS services one of this configurations is needed.

Comment: After debugging, I found out I was missing mySQL's JDBC driver. So that was my problem.